# How to sort desc user names based on uid with entity_load?

Tags: arrays, sorting, drupal, drupal-7

How to **sort descending**, using natcasesort with **entity_load** for realname/name based on uid?

```
  $users = entity_load('user');
    foreach ($users as $uid => $account) {
    if ($uid && !in_array($uid, $exclude)) {
      $form['massadd']['#options'][$account->uid] = $account->realname;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry just figured it out, the problem was I tried against $users instead of $form :)

```
natcasesort($form['massadd']['#options']);
```